# Time needed for Sitecore Active directory to Sync changes into Sitecore

Tags: active-directory, sitecore, sitecore7

I have installed Active directory module for Sitecore, and I'm not sure when the syncing happens between Active Directory and Sitecore.

Let say we added a group to a user in Active directory, How much time is needed for this change to be synched with Sitecore? or should i just open User manager and Sitecore will try to sync the changes at that time?

Comment: what is the setting of your useNotification attribute on the domain config?

Comment: It does not exists in membership/providers/<add name="ad">, should i add 'useNotifications="true"?

Comment: I think that would be default. Try reading through section 4.8 here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc62-65-usletter.pdf   It may not be the same version you are using however.

Comment: I added useNotification="true" there, i will see if changes gets applied to sitecore and update the question here

Comment: @AhmedOkour any joy with this? Please can you update your findings? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The user will appear almost instantaneously if the Sitecore Active Directory module is installed and configured properly, using the [guide](https://exploringsitecore.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc82.pdf) provided by Sitecore. Although for Sitecore 7.2 - 8.1, Sitecore Active Directory module 1.2 is available.

Recently completed a proof of concept that proves it, although it is in the Azure cloud for PaaS solution but it works and ended up writing a [blog post](https://exploringsitecore.wordpress.com/2017/04/12/active-directory-integration-with-sitecore-on-azure-paas/). Refer sections "***Integrating Microsoft Active Directory domain in Sitecore Content Management (CM) Azure Web App***" and "***Check if Active Directory Groups and Users are visible***". Hope it helps.

Happy Sitecoring!